# Parse html field in postgresql query

Tags: html, database, postgresql, parsing

I have a text field that contains an HTML table in a PostgreSQL database. I would like to extract some data from this field: each TR (not from the header) in a row and each TD in a column. Is that possible?

The name of a table is "documentos" and the name of the text field that contains the HTML table is called "props". Props contains following:

```
select props
from documentos
where uidref = 'ee41f201-0049-41e9-9c5d-5c35e2cf73ac'
```

[image: content of props field]

And I would like obtain:

```
444444444 | Investigador | Daniel | Perez
555555555 | Becario      | Jorge  | Fernandez
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Comment: Maybe [this question could be of help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049905/stripping-html-tags-in-postgresql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with PostreSQL and very little with XPATH, but I was able to get something for you:

```
with x as (select
'<TABLE>
        <TBODY>
            <TR>
                <TH class="RowTitle">Identificacion</TH>
                <TH class="colRol">Rol</TH>
            </TR>
            <TR class="tData">
                <TD class="RowTitle">
                    <A href="#">4444</A>
                </TD>
                <TD class="colRow" val="INVARGEXT">Investigador</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR class="tData">
                <TD class="RowTitle">
                    <A href="#">55555</A>
                </TD>
                <TD class="colRow" val="BECARIO">Becario</TD>
            </TR>
        </TBODY>
    </TABLE>'::xml as t
),
y as (select unnest(xpath('//TR[@class="tData"]', t)) td from x)
select -- y.td, -- just to debug
xpath('//TD[@class="RowTitle"]/A/text()', y.td),
xpath('//TD/text()', y.td)
from y;
```

This outputs:

```
    xpath   xpath
1   4444                                        Investigador
2   55555                                       Becario
```

I hope this can be of use.

More information [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-xml.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092952/extracting-multiple-levels-of-xml-data-using-xpath-in-postgres).